# Not able to open excel file when hosted in iis

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have a button wherein it opens an excel file in a pivot format which works perfectly fine with localhost but I get an issue when I host it to IIS it throws the below error :

> Operation unavailable (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))

The code that i have used is :

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=" + DS + ";Initial Catalog=" + Initial_Catalog + ";user id=" + (string)(Session["name"]) + ";password=" + (string)(Session["password"]) + ";"))
{
    string connection = @"OLEDB;Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=" + DS + ";Initial Catalog=" + Initial_Catalog + ";user id=" + (string)(Session["name"]) + ";password=" + (string)(Session["password"]) + ";";
    conn.Open();
    //Create a command, using this connection
    //AdomdCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app;
    app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wkbk = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook)app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)(wkbk.ActiveSheet);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application objAplicacion;
    objAplicacion = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");


    //wkbk.Open(sheet);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotCache pivotCache;
    pivotCache = wkbk.PivotCaches().Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlExternal, Type.Missing);
    //pivotCache.CommandText = "Lempo_Test1";
    pivotCache.Connection = connection;

    pivotCache.MaintainConnection = true;
    pivotCache.CommandText = "Lempo";
    pivotCache.CommandType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCmdType.xlCmdCube;


    // Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)objAplicacion.ActiveSheet;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotTables pivotTables = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotTables)sheet.PivotTables(Type.Missing);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotTable pivotTable = pivotTables.Add(pivotCache, sheet.Cells[1, 1], "PivotTable1", true, Type.Missing);

    pivotTable.SmallGrid = false;
    pivotTable.ShowTableStyleRowStripes = true;
    pivotTable.TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleLight1";
    app.ScreenUpdating = true;
    app.DisplayAlerts = true;
    app.Visible = true;
    app.UserControl = true;
    app.WindowState = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlWindowState.xlMaximized;
    // Response.Redirect("Board.aspx");
}
```

Please help me to resolve this error

Comment: Is it your intent to open the spreadsheet *on the server* where the user will not see be able to see it?

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes user will be able to see it

Comment: No, user cannot see it because that code runs on the server. That's why it works locally, your pc is the server in that case.

Comment: Do not use interop in a web enviroment. It causes problems... Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus).

Comment: Use openXML on the server

Comment: I am using interop and this problem occured when i changed the server . in old server it was working fine.

Comment: @Crowcoder but it used to work before in my old server it just stopped working when i started using the new server

Comment: @FortyTwo can you give me more details on it

Comment: [Getting started with the Open XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/getting-started)

Comment: @FortyTwo but i have already added it as reference

Comment: OpenXML is not going to help if you need the user to use the Excel program. It is for programmatic manipulation of Excel, it doesn't open Microsoft Excel.

Comment: @ashish now you can use :). using `OleDbConnection` is something I wouldn't recommend

Comment: @Crowcoder the user cannot use the excel which runs on the server, as you said ;-)

Comment: @FortyTwo but using oledbconnetion only i am able to connect to analysis server

Comment: I am wondering how it was working in my old server and not working in the new.

Comment: When something worked on an old server, but doesn't work on a new server, it is either a permission problem or missing drivers (software). To test the first, try (temporarily) granting full permissions on your excel file to "Everyone".  (don't forget to undo after your test).  On the old server, see what software was installed (like maybe MS Office or MDAC or something).

Comment: @tgolisch I checked everything and gave all the permissions possible. I had installed Ms office